# how do you sanitize an uploaded image

Tags: javascript, html, security

I understand that a user uploaded image can contain executable code that can run when loaded into an img element. How can that image by sanitized?

Comment: Except for SVG, that is not true.

Comment: @SLaks I think they're talking about an image that is actually an executable with, e.g., a .gif extension, so that, knowing where the script puts it, you can call it and it actually gets run. I can't remember the name for the technique right now, but it is a thing.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: You mean CGI injection? That has nothing to do with `<img>` elements.

Comment: I think this helps outline concepts - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36447/img-tag-vulnerability

Comment: My statement about running code was based on an answer to a question I asked yesterday. Could be wrong. To be more specific, I want to be able to have a user upload a .png file and place it in an img element.

Comment: Yes, I read the security link yesterday but there seems to be a lack of consensus there plus I'm not talking about a linked image but an uploaded one.

Comment: You might be able to perform a content-type sniffing attack with an image, though to exploit this you would need something more complex `<img>`. Your best bet is to set `Content-Type-Options: no-sniff` and try loading the image to make sure it's valid

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, a compression of the image with something like GraphicsMagick or ImageMagic or GD in PHP-- all will allow you to crush any lingering code hidden in an image, so just by re-encoding the image before you display it back to a user or storing it anywhere should do the trick.